# In a specflow test, how do we programmatically bring up the application before the first scenario is run?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Some context:
I am using .Net 6.0.101 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.

I want to test on localhost before I commit and push, and not rely on a deployment to a QA-style environment for example. Here is some pseudo code of what I want to do:

```
[OneTimeSetup]
public void static OneTimeSetup()
{
    pid = OurApplication.Start(); 
    OurApplication.WaitForApplicationToBeStarted(); 
}

[OneTimeTeardown]
public void static OneTimeSetup()
{
    pid.Kill(); 
}
```

I wonder if there is a library I can use that does this level of process or background thread orchestration?